# Getting Last revision number from TortoiseSVN repository and updating the to .net/C++ assembly/executable from Visual Studio IDE

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-c++, tortoisesvn

I want to update the resvision number to the assemblies/executables built in .net 2.0 and Visual C++ MFC by reading the latest revision number from TortoiseSVN repository.
It will be of great help if I can get a function (in .net or VC++) to get the the last revision if I input the repository path and authentication details (if any).
IDE: Visual Studio 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SubWCRev](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html) tool for this task.